# Type hint mixins used in method chaining

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have a few classes and mixins that I want to method chain.  For instance:

```
class Mixin:
   def mix(self, x: int, y: int):
      self.foo = x + y
      return self

class BaseClass:
   ...

class ClassA(BaseClass, Mixin):
   ...

class ClassB(BaseClass, Mixin):
   ...

a = ClassA()
a.mix(x, y) \
 .do_foo() \
 .do_bar()

b = ClassB()
b.mix(x, y) \
 .do_baz()
```

I plan to only use `Mixin` with some subclasses of `BaseClass`, so I thought I would just typehint `Mixin.mix` with `BaseClass`.  However, my linter complains that BaseClass does not have the methods `do_foo`, `do_bar`, or `do_baz`...  which, sure, technically, that's correct, but in practice, the code will run fine.  How can I get mypy and the linter to stop kvetching at me?  A number of subclasses may end up using `Mixin`, so doing `Union[ClassA, ClassB, etc.]` is unappealing.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add a type hint to the `Mixin.mix` method indicating that it's going to return an instance of the `Mixin` class (technically, any instances of the `ClassA` and `ClassB` classes are also instances of the `Mixin` class due to subclassing).

```
class Mixin:
    def mix(self, x: int, y: int) -> 'Mixin':
        ...
        return self
```

Alternatively, if you're sure that the `Mixin` class will only be used for subclasses of `BaseClass`, then I'd also recommend trying to use a `TypeVar` bound to `BaseClass` and its subclasses:

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', bound='BaseClass')

class Mixin:
    def mix(self: T, x: int, y: int) -> T:
        ...
        return self
```

Comment: Hm, the latter seemed promising, but then I get `The erased type of self <class> is not a supertype of its class` :(